# Info about enterprise level application server architecture components required

Tags: performance, load-testing

I want to gain knowledge about full architecture of enterprise level application deployment. I mean, place and positions of various components like load balancers, server multiple instances etc. How these multiple instances fit into the full enterprise level application architecture. Actually i have to monitor(for performance/load testing) a j2ee application deployed on weblogic server. The server is running with multiple instances, have load balancers and other enterprise level components. So i want to know how these multiple instances and load balancers fit into the picture and work. Can anybody tell me any link or guide having such info?

EDIT: In simple words i want to know about the enterprise level server architecture structure which includes load balancers, server instances, clustering etc as components.

Comment: One specific question at a time please.

Answer (score 1):

There is no canonical deployment model for enterprise level applications.  The best way to learn about the deployment model for your J2EE application on a Weblogic server is to **ask the people who own it**.